# JMS Translation Bundle does not extract keys from controllers in Symfony2 - getTranslationMessages()

Tags: symfony, internationalization, jms, translation

I am using JMS Translation Bundle in my Symfony 2 project.

All translations in the twig files are working great. If I write new keys that need to be translated and run the extract command from command line they get extracted and I can then set appropriate values.

My question is this: I have some messages / keys in the Symfony2 controllers that need to be first extracted and then translated by me. I am writing them like this:

```
$translator = $this->get('translator');
$message = $translator->trans('FavTrans.No_trans_found');
```

When I run the extract command now the new translation key doesn't get created and I can't edit it or add translation to it. The command that I run is below.

```
php app/console translation:extract en ro fr --dir=./src/Smart/Bundle/AdminBundle/Controller/ --output-dir=./app/Resources/translations --output-format=xliff --domain=SmartAdminBundle --keep
```

I have tried to implement the "TranslationContainerInterface" like said [here](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSTranslationBundle/master/usage)

The problem is I do not know what I need to write in the getTranslationMessages function.

Can anyone help? Either telling me that my extract command is wrong, or am I doing the translation in the controller in an unapropriate way? Or if somebody knows what code I need to write in the getTranslationMessages() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution.
You need to provide the domain on which the translations should be extracted to.

```
$translator = $this->get('translator');
$translator->trans('FavTrans.No_trans_found', array(), 'SmartAdminBundle')
```